# How should I model my database so that every student entity in my database has a grade related to each course entity?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, object, mapping

I'm making a Java CRUD application that would serve as a college management tool. My database contains 5 tables (College, Study Programme, Course, Professor and Student). I would like to show and manage each students grade for each course. I mapped student and course as a many to many relationship -> 1 student can take many courses at a time, and 1 course has many students attending. Do I need to create an additional table or should I implement a HashMap containing Student and Integer(grade) as a key-value pair inside my Course object?
Or is there a much better way to achieve this?

Here's my Student POJO:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
public class Student extends Person implements Serializable{

    private String JMBAG;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    private List<Course> courses;

}
```

and here's my Course POJO:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
public class Course extends CollegeManagerEntity implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private Integer year;

    private Integer ects;

    private Integer numberOfClasses;

    private Integer numberOfAuditorialExercises;

    private Integer numberOfLaboratoryExercises;

    private Integer numberOfConstructionalExercises;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Professor> professors;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Student> students;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private List<StudyProgramme> studyProgrammes;

}
```

Comment: yes, you do need an additional database table. every many-to-many relationship requires a separate database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to use HashMap, how it will be implemented in DB? What will the database schema look like?

You need a new table by following RDBMS approaches. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e6fl.png).
The new entity will look like that:

```
@Entity
public class CourseMember {

    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
    private Course course;

    @Column
    private Integer grade;
}
```

And then you need to map your new entity to Student and Course classes.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<CourseMember> courseMemberList;

}

@Entity
public class Course {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<CourseMember> courseMemberList;

}
```

Comment: I see your point. I wasn't sure how to implement a Map from the db perspective. This makes a lot of sense, though. Thank you a lot for your answer, it was very helpful. Everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Try to design DB schema first and then map it to Java code. Good luck!